# Reading environmental variables in PowerShell or cmd yield different results

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have been puzzling over an issue with environmental variables in Windows 7.

We have a Jenkins server which cannot find the SSH keys in the `%HOME%` environmental variable as it wants to access the path:

```
/c/users/jenkins
```

However if I use

```
echo %HOME%
```

in a normal command prompt window as my Jenkins user then the result is

```
C:\users\jenkins
```

However, if I use the environment command in Windows PowerShell I also get

```
/c/user/jenkins
```

In the normal GUI accessible from the system properties - advanced tag -> environmental I get the following

```
C:\users\jenkins
```

I have tried setting them back, but the issue persists. In so far as Jenkins gets the same output as PowerShell.

How do I set them back? (Not that cmd and the Windows system think that they are set wrong.)
How on earth does accessing the same environmental variable give me different outputs?
Is there a way in which this can occur?
Where are they stored so I can manually edit where they are stored?

Comment: env is not a regular Windows / Powershell command, it must be something installed somewhere else in your machine

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the machine was rebooted overnight by a colleague and the issue has disappeared. I will be on the lookout for this occurring again but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by @Luis, the `env` command is not part of PowerShell. It is likely provided by some other set of utilities that you have installed and is intended to emulate the [Linux `env` command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_env.htm).

To refer to an environment variable in PowerShell, use the `$env:<variable-name>` syntax or the environment provider - `Get-Content env:\<variable-name>`.

To set an environment variable, you can use `$env:<variable-name> = "<variable-value>"`

For more information, try running `help about_Environment_Variables` in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you unfortunately the machine was rebooted last night and the issue has since not represented itself. I prefer getting to the root cause so it's a shame I cannot investigate more.